# Only access to my google cloud endpoints from my website and android app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I write a endpoints in google app engine, i have a website and android app which using that endpoints and website have address is http://example.com. How my endpoints only service requests from http://example.com?.
- Similar for android, my endpoints only service for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set client ids in your endpoints by following https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#client_ids_and_audiences

And you can get client id for your web and android app from developer consoles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The client_ids only provide a token for permission to authenticate with google, after that we must check user in back-end. Have another way to protect in our back-end not use google account?